# Rails 4 app: Android UC Browser using wrong HTTP method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, redirect, android-browser

I have a Rails 4 application and recently noticed in Rollbar logs a couple (11 as of now) errors which are caused by wrong HTTP methods for given paths (according to standard Rails RESTful `resources` routing). It's either `POST /resources/:id` or `PATCH /resources`. As far as I understand, they should be the other way around. All of the occurrences happened for user(s) of UC Browser 10 running on Android.

Am I doing something wrong? I don't get any such errors for other browsers and app seems to run normally (creating and editing above mentioned `resources` works fine). So, I'm guessing there's something wrong with UC Browser. Does it ignore method changes with redirects? Is there something I can do to prevent (or work around) this problem?